# SELECT mysql query to get first 100 numbers (1-100)

Tags: mysql, database, select

i want a mysql select query where i can get first 100 numbers starting from 1 and ending to 100 without CTE or any procedures just want a query only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need a list of integers I use

```
SELECT help_keyword_id num 
FROM mysql.help_keyword 
HAVING num BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
ORDER BY 1;
```